# Google Apps - Mysql connection fails

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am testing mysql connection from google apps/google sheets.

```
function test() {
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/", "admin", "admin");
  debugger;
}
```

error message: `Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.`

This is a mySQL db on a cloud VPS (hosted on Hetzner). In the past I had no issue to connect to the same DB, it started failing about 1 year ago.

The DB allows remote access for this user on port 3306. I read in some posts the need to whitelist the google IPs on my server/DB. How am i supposed to do this? Is it the reason for failure?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the database name in the string, like this:

```
Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME", "admin", "admin");
```

Comment: Same Error with this string